# Git/linux all-in-one find command

Tags: linux, git, find

I've got a nix command going through all git repos in a directory and switching to a default branch.
The last line is supposed to delete all listed branches. It works when executing it by itself but not in this command. I tried things like escaping the `, putting quotes around it, ... but I can't get it to work.

This is the error I get:
`fatal: branch name required`

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be grateful :)

PS: I know this isn't best practice and you should just automatically delete stuff etc... That's why I use "-d" and not "-D". This is also to cleanup my environment as I tend to have multiple repos with lots of branches over time.

```
find . \
    -maxdepth 2 -type d \
    -name ".git" \
    -execdir python3 -c 'import os; print("\33[33m----------------------------------------------  " + os.path.abspath(".") + "  ----------------------------------------------\33[0m")' \; \
    -execdir git checkout development \; \
    -execdir git branch -d `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" 'refs/heads/bugfix' 'refs/heads/feature' 'refs/heads/release' 'refs/heads/hotfix' 'refs/heads/master'` \;
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting? Is it possible that some of your repos don't have a `development` branch?

Comment: `git for-each-ref ...` gets expanded before `find` command runs, which is not what you want.

Comment: @mnestorov sorry forgot to include the error -__- Every repo has a development branch. There is no exception :)

Comment: @Philippe Any idea on how to solve it? Or is there another way of doing the same thing with different commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . \
    -maxdepth 2 -type d \
    -name ".git" \
    -execdir echo git checkout development \; \
    -execdir python3 -c 'import os; print("\33[33m----------------------------------------------  " + os.path.abspath(".") + "  ----------------------------------------------\33[0m")' \; \
    -execdir bash -c 'branches="$(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/bugfix refs/heads/feature refs/heads/release refs/heads/hotfix refs/heads/master)"; test -n "$branches" && echo git branch -d "$branches" || echo "No branch found"' \;
```

remove the 2 echoes when you see it does what you wanted.

Comment: It just displays the line it's executing `git branch -d master`

Comment: Have you removed the 2 echoes, as said in the answer ?

Comment: Oh I had 2 echoes myself for testing purposes. Overlooked yours. Removed those too then I get `fatal: branch name required`.

Comment: That means in some of your repositories, `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/bugfix refs/heads/feature refs/heads/release refs/heads/hotfix refs/heads/master` gives nothing.
So `git branch -d` does not know what to do.

Comment: So I can actually just ignore that line?

Comment: Updated answer to handle this.

Comment: Didn't notice the echo again :') Works! Ty

Answer (score 2):

It is better to simplify it in 2 commands or better in a `shell` script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# array of all .git
mapfile -t all_dot_git < <(find  . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git');

# loop over them and do what ever you want
for dir in ${all_dot_git[@]};do
    echo $dir;
done
```

Sample output:

```
./blog/.git
./wh_ticket_bot/.git
./ipwebcam-gst/.git
./gitlab-tmp/.git
./project/.git
./curly/.git
./wh_tools_bot/.git
./derak-website/.git
./bash-CLI-template/.git
./ldc/.git
./btc/.git
./en4fa.ir/.git
./sshpf/.git
./ppst/.git
./png/.git
./gitlab-docker/.git
./migrate/.git
./fflive/.git
./wp-docker-pattern/.git
./wh-tools-bot/.git
./derak-panel-review/.git
./oxv/.git
./101-tutorial/.git
./shakibamoshiribot/.git
./high-traffic-site-optimization/.git
./isms/.git
./dotvim/.git
```

**check branch name** with the help or `pushd` and `popd`

```
#!/bin/bash

# array of all .git
mapfile -t all_dot_git < <(find  . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git');

# loop over them and do what ever you want
for dir in ${all_dot_git[@]};do
    # set actual path (remove .git)
    dir=$(dirname  $dir);
    # or just ${dir%/*} variable substitution 
    
    # cd to $dir
    pushd $dir
    # do the task
    git branch;
    # return back to first place
    popd;
done
```

Sample output:

```
./blog
~/git-repo/blog ~/git-repo
* main
~/git-repo
./wh_ticket_bot
~/git-repo/wh_ticket_bot ~/git-repo
  add_ticket_support
* master
~/git-repo
./ipwebcam-gst
~/git-repo/ipwebcam-gst ~/git-repo
* master
~/git-repo
./gitlab-tmp
~/git-repo/gitlab-tmp ~/git-repo
  dev
* master
  staging
~/git-repo
./project
...
...
```

Comment: Think I can make this work with some more tweaking :) Thx!